# Windows Phone image not displaying

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I'm creating an app which I can select items on combobox to display an image on the screen.

I have 196 png files in `/assets/flags/`. when I select an item on combobox, the image does not display. There are no errors or exceptions. What am i doing wrong?

```
private void okBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Afghanistan")
    {
        imageBox.Source = 
             new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/flags/af.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    }
    else if (myComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Danmark")
    {
        imageBox.Source = 
             new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/flags/dk.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the values? Testing for equality on complicated strings is error prone..

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the code inside any Button Click event "okBtn",
Try putting "IF" block inside combobox's default event which is **Selection Changed**.

`Private Sub myComboBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As Args)`

```
          End Sub
```

Comment: then how can i apply when clicking the button?

Answer (score 0):

well i have solved the problem. the `combobox` selection must equal to the values and not equal to the strings

```
if (myComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
                imageBox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/flags/af.png", UriKind.Absolute));
}
else if (myComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
                imageBox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/flags/dk.png", UriKind.Absolute));
}
```